# PN Junction under strong forward bias?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

Why does the PN Junction never ceases to exist even under strong forward bias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The p-n junction is a feature of the materials. The n-doped material has an excess of electrons, which carry negative charge, while the p-doped material has an excess of "holes," which act like positive charge carriers.  The junction is simply the region where the chemical composition of the semiconductor changes from the one to the other.  Forward-biased voltage causes both types of charge carrier to move towards the junction.  The electrons fall into the holes, and current flows, but the underlying crystal structure doesn't change.

However under *very* strong forward bias, the [magic smoke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_smoke) is released from the material near the p-n junction; you could say that the junction ceases to exist at that point.